# How to calcucate a product of n adjecent numbers using ArrayList and subList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Im trying to solve EulerProblem8 https://projecteuler.net/problem=8 and i just don't get it , what am i doing wrong ? I tried before with a file and ArrayList but couldn't pull it off ... Whats wrong , the subtsrings , the loops , the *= ... i dont know what to do anymore?

```
package largestproductinaseries_ep8;

//The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number 
//that have the greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.
//Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number 
//that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

public class LargestProductInASeries_EP8 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    String bigNum = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934" +
                    "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843" +
                    "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511" +
                    "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557" +
                    "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113" +
                    "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749" +
                    "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866" +
                    "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776" +
                    "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243" +
                    "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397" +
                    "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482" +
                    "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474" +
                    "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881" +
                    "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586" +
                    "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042" +
                    "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408" +
                    "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188" +
                    "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606" +
                    "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725" +
                    "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";


    int a           = 0;
    String peace    = "";
    String onePeace = "";
    int onePeaceNum = 0;
    int multi = 1;
    int maxMulti = 0;
    while(a<bigNum.length()-12){
        peace = bigNum.substring(a, a+13);
        if(!peace.contains("0")){
            for(int i = 12; i>=0; i--){
                onePeace = peace.substring(i, i+1);
                onePeaceNum = Integer.parseInt(onePeace);
                multi *= onePeaceNum;
                if(multi>maxMulti){
                    maxMulti = multi;
                }
            }
            multi = 1;
        }
        a++;
    }  
    System.out.println(maxMulti);
}
}
//23514624000 this is Euler answer
// 2091059712 this is my output
```

Comment: Read the javadoc of hasNext() and nextInt(). It doesn't return the next digit. Use your debugger, or even simple System.out.println(), to know what actually happens in the code.

Comment: What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: You do realise that 23514624000 does not fit in an int? Have you debugged and checked if any of you numbers become negative?

Comment: @RogerLindsjö OMG I initialy started with multi and maxMulti variables to be of type long but now i saw they are ints ,... IT WORKS when they are long..Jesus..ty man , was blinded by the writing and rewriting and trying again and again...

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in your implementation, you never reset the mult value so you keep multiplying and you don't stop after 13 numbers. 
Your code should be:

```
            if (mult > maxMult) {
                maxMult = mult;
                mult = 1;
            } else {
                mult = 1;
            }
```

Comment: @AleksandarStojanovic I have tried with the numbers embedded into the code(instead of loading from file) and it gives the right answer. Have you checked the content of the list?

Comment: Yeah , i checked a couple of times.. I tried now by using a String instead of a file and a ArrayList , but still doesn't work...